# Update bytea data with NULL in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have a bytea field which contains data I want to replace with NULL. I tried the following syntax:

```
update ir_act_report_xml set report_rml_content_data = E'\\000'::bytea, report_sxw_content_data = E'\\000'::bytea where id = 365;
```

But it then returns 00 instead of being NULL.

What is the correct syntax for updating the bytea field to NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the keyword `NULL`:

```
UPDATE ir_act_report_xml SET
   report_rml_content_data = NULL,
   report_sxw_content_data = NULL
 WHERE id = 365;
```